# I want an example of a sequence that satisfies $\mid x(n) - x(n-1)\mid \to 0$ but not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences

I want an example of a sequence that satisfies $\mid x(n) - x(n-1)\mid \to 0$
but not Cauchy ?
I tried to find such sequence 
$x(n)=1/2,1/3,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,,,,$
it's not Cauchy since it is not converges (has infinitely limit points)
and the difference between any successive terms goes to zero ..
I asked my doctor but he said the difference is constant (not zero)since the sub-sequences here are constants 
So can any one gives me a hint for this problem :)?
thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237655/pseudo-cauchy-sequence) and [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55735/pseudo-cauchy-sequences-are-they-also-cauchy?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try
$$
x_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.
$$

A slightly different example would be $x_n =\ln n$.

Comment: Thanks for replying :)),,,yes that's absolutely true the difference between any successive terms is 1/n which converges to zero while the infinte series is divergent,,Thanks again:)

Answer (score 2):

Another example is $$x_n = \sin \sqrt n \, .$$ As in [Prove the divergence of the sequence $\left\{ \sin(n) \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238997/prove-the-divergence-of-the-sequence-left-sinn-right-n-1-infty),
the set of limit points is the entire interval $[-1, 1]$, and
using the mean value theorem it is easy to see that
$$
| x_{n} - x_{n-1} | \le \frac {1}{2 \sqrt {n-1}} \to 0 \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

$1, 1/2,0,1/3,2/3,1,3/4,2/4,1/4, 0, \dots.$