# A sequence $\{a_n\}$ that diverges but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to 0} |a_n-a_{n+1}| =0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences

What is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that diverges and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to 0} |a_n-a_{n+1}| =0$

Comment: Do you mean $a_{n+1}$ or $a_n + 1$? Btw I think you want $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Do you want the _sequence_ to diverge, or the _sum_ to diverge.  Because $a_n = 1$ converges perfectly fine $a_n\to 1$, but $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: See also: [Pseudo-Cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237655), [I want an example of a sequence that satisfies $|x(n) - x(n-1)| \to 0$ but not Cauchy](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494962), [If $\{x_n\}$ satisfies that $x_{n+1} - x_n$ goes to $0$, is $\{x_n\}$ a Cauchy sequence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633602/if-x-n-satisfies-that-x-n1-x-n-goes-to-0-is-x-n-a-cauchy-s), [Cauchy Sequence of Real Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75840/cauchy-sequence-of-real-numbers), etc.

Comment: By the way, if $\lvert a_{n+1} - a_n \rvert \leq u_n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$ converges, then $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 4):

Take
$$
a_n=\sqrt{n}
$$ then note that, for $n\ge1$,
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider harmonic series.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/729240)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "This does not provide an answer to the question." Actually it does, very much so.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich It very much hints to an answer of the question. Perhaps adding the words 'the partial sums sequence of" between "consider" and harmonic" makes this more direct, but hints are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two good answers you already got, you could also take

$$a_n:=\log n\implies a_{n+1}-a_n=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;\ldots$$