# A condition for convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider the sequence $s_n=\sqrt{n}$. Although $(s_{n+1}-s_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the sequence is not convergent (since it is unbounded).

(This is a very common example in study of  Cauchy sequences where, by this example, it is remarked that making consecutive difference smaller is not sufficient for Cauchy condition.)

Suppose we put such a condition on a sequence; i.e. suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $(x_{n+1}-x_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ **and $(x_n)$ is bounded**. Can we say that $(x_n)$ must be convergent? If not, what condition, instead of boundedness, will guarantee the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)$?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n/107344#107344).

Comment: I added at the end, **If not, what condition, instead of boundedness, will guarantee the convergence** (Since I had not thought about the example in answer below, so I assed this extra point in question; I don't get why it is closing.

Comment: In the first line of above question, I shortly mentioned why it is not Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ (equivalent to say, why it is not convergent).

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494962/42969, with the example $x_n = \sin(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: @Beginner: In a complete metric space, the convergent sequences are *exactly* the Cauchy sequences. Perhaps you can clarify  what kind of  *“condition, instead of boundedness”* you are thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

No. Think about
$$0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{5}, ...$$

Comment: This is certainly nice example (I would also like to see conditions under which convergence will hold).

Comment: Nice, but not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107344/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495839/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but it was quicker to answer the question than to search for duplicates... (I know it is bad, sorry ^^)